# Reading HDFS extended attributes in HiveQL

Tags: hive, metadata, hdfs

I am working on a use case where we would like to add metadata (e.g. load time, data source...) to raw files as HDFS extended attributes (xattrs).
I was wondering if there was a way for HiveQL to retrieve such metadata in queries in the result set.
This would avoid storing such metadata in each record within raw files.
Would a custom Hive SerDe be a way to make such xattrs available? Otherwise, do you see another way to make this possible?

I am still relatively novice with this, so bear with me if I misused terms.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be other ways to implement it, but after I discovered [Hive virtual column](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+VirtualColumns) 'INPUT__FILE__NAME' containing the URL of the source HDFS file, I create a User-Defined Function in Java to read its extended attributes. This function can be used in a Hive query as:

```
XAttrSimpleUDF(INPUT__FILE__NAME,'user.my_key')
```

The (quick and dirty) Java source code of the UDF looks like:

```
public class XAttrSimpleUDF extends UDF {

  public Text evaluate(Text uri, Text attr) {
    if(uri == null || attr == null) return null;

    Text xAttrTxt = null;
    try {
        Configuration myConf = new Configuration();

        //Creating filesystem using uri
        URI myURI = URI.create(uri.toString());
        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(myURI, myConf);

        // Retrieve value of extended attribute
        xAttrTxt = new Text(fs.getXAttr(new Path(myURI), attr.toString()));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return xAttrTxt;
  }
}
```

I didn't test the performance of this when querying very large data sets.
I wished that extended attributes could be retrieved directly as a virtual column in a way similar to using virtual column INPUT__FILE__NAME.